# How can can you write a prime number as a product of prime numbers?

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization

According to the fundamental theorem of arithmetic (unique factorization theorem), you can write every number as the product of some prime numbers, for example $33 = 11 \cdot 3$.

However, how can you do this when you're dealing with a prime number? If you write $29 = 29 \cdot 1$ you use 1 and that isn't a prime number. Should you just write $29 = 29^1$?

Comment: yes, every prime $p$ is just $p^1$.

Comment: The fun question is: what is the prime factorization of $1$?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Any number to the zeroth? But that wouldn't be unique..

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, "product of 0 primes" is good enough for me.

Comment: From an algebraic point of view, $1$ doesn't admit a prime factorization :) When you look up the definitions of primes and unique factorization domains, you see that only *non-invertible* ring elements have a prime factorization. $1$ has the rare property of being an invertible integer, so it doesn't get to have a prime factorization.

Comment: 1 is still single ^-^ And neither prime nor composite.

Answer (score 5):

A single number, like $31$ or $7$, is in fact a product as far as mathematics is concerned.  It is a product of $1$ integer.

Indeed, you can even have a product of $0$ integers.  This is defined to be $1$, because $1$ is the identity element of multiplication.  (See Qiaochu's comment.)

When we say that an integer has a unique prime factorization, we mean it can be written as a product of some *nonnegative integer* number of primes.  Thus, "$2 \cdot 2 \cdot 23$", "$31$", "$7$", and "$\quad$" are all valid prime factorizations.